# Back to previous page with header in PHP is not working properly

Tags: php, header

I have been using header for change password functionality, i have multiple pages like page1,page2,page3 like that. everywhere on top menu i have **Change Password** button..so after clicking submit, user should redirect to same page where he clicked change password with a message like password change successfully or failed.

i wrote code like..

```
header("Location: /".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?res=3");
```

this is redirecting properly..but as iam using ***myhost/myproj/mypage.php*** its redirecting with double localhost like
***myhost/myhost/myproj/mypage.php*** which is not existed.

now i need to clear my base url & only it should redirects like ***myhost/myproj/mypage.php***

Any suggestions/solutions will be grateful. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '',  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //To remove query string

header("Location: ".$url."?res=3");
```

**Note:** I have removed `/` from your syntax.

Comment: what a fool iam :P ..i missed so simple thing..thanq rakesh :)

Comment: its working fine now..but parameters(?res=3) i should remove when it redirects to that page..how it can be done Rikesh??

Comment: Sorry. Didn't get you. Do you  want to remove it ? Or you want to pass it on redirected page ?

Comment: i will explain you clearly rikesh..the password change functionality works for me like..if res=1 it should display wrong old password in page..samething like..if res=2 it shud display password doesnt match & if res=3 password successfully updated..now when i try to to change password with old wrong password..it throws an error and url is like myhost/myproj/mypage.php?res=1. thats good..when i tried again to give rightone..then in url it is shown some thing like myhost/myproj/mypage.php?res=1?res=3. So not working properly..how could i solve this rikesh?

Comment: @smallerik - For that you have to remove query string from your current url. I have update my answer. Please check.

Comment: oh superb..u r genius rikesh..u solved my prob so easily..thanq..thanq soo much :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the complete(absolute) path OR give the proper relative path

I guess the issue is becaue your relative path is not corect

Make use of "`../`" OR "`./`"

Comment: i removed / and its working fine prashanth..thanks for your prompt reply..but i should remove arguments(?res=3) while it go back to previous page..how it can be done? any ideas?

Comment: hi Prasanth Bendra..what u said is right..when i go back..its reflecting that page..how can i over come this?